# What's the datatype of lambda-expressions?

Tags: c#, lambda, types

i have a small question i just can't figure out myself, what is the datatype of a lambda-expression like this:
    `x => x>0`
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Might want to read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: it's `Func<T,TResult>` in your case `Func<int,bool>` where `bool` is return type and `int x` is input

Answer (score 5):

It's just a `Func<T, bool>` where `T` is type of `x`.

In general, `Func<T, TResult>` is the one of predefined delegate types for a method that accepts one argument of type `T` (`x` in your case) and returns some value of the type `TResult` (`bool` in your case)

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: but what'S the datatype of the whole thing ?

Comment: it's `<Func<T,TResult>` in your case `Func<int,bool>` where `bool` is return type and `int x` is input

Answer (score 4):

Lambda expressions don't have a definite type. The types that a lambda expression can be implicitly converted to is either delegate or Expression type.

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

"Note that lambda expressions in themselves do not have a type because the common type system has no intrinsic concept of "lambda expression." However, it is sometimes convenient to speak informally of the "type" of a lambda expression. In these cases the type refers to the delegate type or Expression type to which the lambda expression is converted."

For your specific example some of the types to which the lambda can be assigned are:

```
  Predicate<int> predicate = x => x > 0;
  Func<int, bool> func = x => x > 0;
  Expression<Func<int, bool>> expression = x => x > 0;
```

Comment: Note that the parameter and return types are not even necessarily `int` or `bool`. For example, 0 is implicitly convertible to all enum types and `Func<DayOfWeek, bool>` works just as well. Alternatively, one could define a custom type with a less than operator overload that returns something other than bool. It is also worth considering an expression like `x => x.Length > 0`. Here x could be any array type or string or any type that has a property Length.